# Data types - overflow

Tags: c

If we consider overflow in long long unsigned int, after overflow it will generate a positive number always.
for example the below code generate positive numbers when a is not multiple of 2.
but if a is multiple of 2 like 2,4,6... after overflow it prints 0.
why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define LLU long long unsigned int
#define a 5
int main()
{
    LLU t=2;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        t=t*a;
        printf("%llu\n",t) ;

    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You meant 2, 4, 8, not 2, 4, 6, right?

Comment: because it can overflows to 0, sometimes

Comment: What do you mean by *it overflows to 0* and how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Unsigned integers are non-negative, both before and after overflow.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I have written right it's 2,4,6 .

Comment: @hardmath : yeah you are right but it could overflow to some another positive number NOT necessarily be zero .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the repeated multiplication by `2` yields zero on overflow is the same as the reason why repeated multiplication of 1 by 10 yields zero when the number of digits is fixed: every multiplication produces a binary number composed of a single `1`, and all zeros after it.

Here is how it works for an 8-bit number:

```
Power of 2 Decimal     Binary  Last 8 bits
---------- ------- ---------- ------------
         0       1          1    00000001
         1       2         10    00000010
         2       4        100    00000100
         3       8       1000    00001000
         4      16      10000    00010000
         5      32     100000    00100000
         6      64    1000000    01000000
         7     128   10000000    10000000
         8     256  100000000    00000000 <<== 1 "falls off the end"
```

Note that the last eight bits of the eights power of 2 are all zeros, so if we had only 8 bits, we would get zero after 8-th multiplication. All subsequent multiplications would yield zero as well.

The same exact thing is going on with `LLU`, except it takes 64 multiplications to get the number to overflow to zero.

**Edit:** All even numbers have zero at the end of their binary representation, for the same reason all decimal numbers divisible by ten have at least one zero at the end of their decimal representation. Therefore, if you start with any even number, not necessarily a power of two, each multiplication would increase the number of zeros at the end of the number by the number of zeros in the number being multiplied. For example, if you multiply by `14`, which is `1110` in binary, the result would get an additional zero at the end. If you multiply by `12`, which is `1100`, you would get two additional zeros.

The overall result is the same as with multiplying by two: since each multiplication increases the number of tail zeros by at least one, you would end up with all zeros in at most 64 multiplications for `LLU`.

Comment: But it is not happening with only when we multiply a number that is power of 2 but when it is not power of two also like 6 .

Comment: @Abhishek The same exact mechanism is in play for all even numbers, though, because all even numbers by definition have at least one `2` among their factors. Please see the edit for more explanation.

Comment: Yes you are right and best part is to analyse a binary number with help of decimal number . Instead of even number we can take any number multiple of 10 in case of decimal. It is now clearly visible.
Thanks.